# How to fix bugged Chrome dev tools?

Tags: windows, google-chrome

Chrome dev tools are an invaluable tool for my day-to-day work. However every now and then they bug out in the manner shown below. I haven't found any specific way to force the issue to reproduce, it happens at seemingly random times.

[image: Sample image]

As can be seen, the element has properties defined for it (padding), but none of them are displayed below the overview. This is the same for all elements.

More often than not, restarting the browser nor reopening the dev tools fix the issue.

I'm running Chrome 43 on Windows as of this writing. What is causing this, and more importantly, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reinstalling chrome yet? I had a similar issue a while ago where the whole dev tools package would crash. I fixed it by installing the beta version of chrome (can be dangerous, use at own risk)

You can get the beta version here: https://www.google.com.au/chrome/browser/beta.html